# UpdatePanel in mode conditional gets updated - why?

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I just recently started to use the UpdatePanel and do not understand if what I get is standard behavior:

With an Update Panel defined like this...

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true"/>

<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel_Repeater" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
    <ContentTemplate>                                          
         <asp:Repeater ...      
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

is it normal that the panel gets updated after a Postback caused by a control (DropDownList - SelectedIndexChanged) that isn't inside any UpdatePanel?

I want this to be updated only if called explicitly by UpdatePanel_Repeater.Update() or on PageLoad

Comment: Why use an UpdatePanel at all? Why not write a little JavaScript that does exactly what you need?

Comment: Basically because I wouldn't know how to do it... and then the UpdatePanel seems to do what I want. A partial reload of a page, according to the event that has been fired. It already works pretty good, but I'm wondering if that behavior described is standard.

Comment: UpdatePanel is about one the worst things you can do to your application. Learn some JavaScript, learn how to make AJAX requests. You'll end up with a far easier solution to support, it will run faster, and it will waste less resources.

Comment: Thank you mason for that advise; I put it on the list of things to work out as soon as I have some time